# Merging multiple lists into one in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `X`. I want to append elements of `X[0][0],X[1][0],X[2][0]`, `X[1][0],X[1][1],X[2][1]` and so on. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
X=[[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[8], [4], [6], [2], [3]],[[9], [1], [2], [5], [1]]]
X1=[]
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    for j in range(0,len(X[0])):
        X1=X[i][j]
        X1.append(X)
```

The current output is

```
[1,
 [[[1, [...]], [2, [...]], [3, [...]], [4, [...]], [5, [...]]],
  [[8, [...]], [4, [...]], [6, [...]], [2, [...]], [3, [...]]],
  [[9, [...]], [1, [...]], [2, [...]], [5, [...]], [...]]]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[1,8,9], [2,4,1], [3,6,2], [4,2,5], [5,3,1]]
```

Comment: You probably want to do `X1.append(X[i][j])` & remove the line just above that

Comment: Unfortunately ```X1.append(X[i][j])``` yields ```[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [8], [4], [6], [2], [3], [9], [1], [2], [5], [1]]``` which is not the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the sublists using `zip`, then add each inner lists, you can use list-comprehension for it:

```py
>>> [x+y+z for (x,y,z) in zip(X[0], X[1], X[2])]

[[1, 8, 9], [2, 4, 1], [3, 6, 2], [4, 2, 5], [5, 3, 1]]
```

Or you can use `reduce` from `functools` and pass unpacked list to `zip` if you are not sure how many sublists are there

```py
>>> from functools import reduce 
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, v) for v in zip(*X)]

[[1, 8, 9], [2, 4, 1], [3, 6, 2], [4, 2, 5], [5, 3, 1]]
```

Another approach is to call `sum` iterating the unpacked list passed to `zip` as suggested by @Mad Physicist in the comment:

```py
>>> [sum(x, start=[]) for x in zip(*X)]

[[1, 8, 9], [2, 4, 1], [3, 6, 2], [4, 2, 5], [5, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: @user19977266: `[sum(x, start=[]) for x in zip(*X)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy instead of dealing with loops

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[8], [4], [6], [2], [3]],[[9], [1], [2], [5], [1]]])
// reshape and transpose
array = array.reshape(3,5).T


array will be

array([[1, 8, 9],
       [2, 4, 1],
       [3, 6, 2],
       [4, 2, 5],
       [5, 3, 1]])
```

Comment: You might want to determine the shape `(3, 5)` dynamically from the input list.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can help a lot here. First when get rid of the inner-most single-item lists, turning the three `list[list[int]]` into three `list[int]`. Then, those can be used to create a `np.ndarray`. We then transpose this array to get the desired result.

```
import numpy as np

X = [[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]],
     [[8], [4], [6], [2], [3]],
     [[9], [1], [2], [5], [1]]]

a = [[item[0] for item in sublist] for sublist in X]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [8, 4, 6, 2, 3], [9, 1, 2, 5, 1]]

a = np.array(a).T
# array([[1, 8, 9],
#        [2, 4, 1],
#        [3, 6, 2],
#        [4, 2, 5],
#        [5, 3, 1]])
```

Comment: If you're going to use numpy, why are you using loops instead of plain indexing?

Answer (score 0):

As your list (X) contains a few lists with the same size, it's number of elements can be just indexes_per_list = len(X[0]).
We can then search for the index in every sub-list, and append the correct index.
In order to remove the square brackets, we just use explode (*):

```
output = []
indexes_per_list = len(X[0])

for i in range(indexes_per_list):
    item = []
    
    for l in X:
        item.append(*l[i])
    
    output.append(item)

print(output)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If there are fewer and more than 3 elements:

```
import numpy as np
x=[[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[8], [4], [6], [2], [3]],[[9], [1], [2], [5], [1]]]
 
x = np.asarray(x)
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0],x.shape[1]).T
x
```

Output for(3,5,1):

```
array([[1, 8, 9],
       [2, 4, 1],
       [3, 6, 2],
       [4, 2, 5],
       [5, 3, 1]])
```

Output for (4,5,1):

```
array([[1, 8, 9, 9],
       [2, 4, 1, 1],
       [3, 6, 2, 2],
       [4, 2, 5, 5],
       [5, 3, 1, 1]])
```